# SSIS: Refections invocation error--Is there any way to get more information?

Tags: c#, ssis

Techies--

I have a 2012 SSIS package that executes successfully in my local environment. Unfortunately, it does not execute successfully on a new environment. I see an incomplete looking message: "[package name]: Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation."  The last time I saw such a generic error of this nature, one of the DLLs was missing for a C# task. Once the library was provided, the failure disappeared. Something similar may be happening, but this message is so broad, I can't tell. Is there a way to trap more of this message?

Comment: How about add a try..catch block to the script task and write to the log in the catch block?  Make sure to capture the inner exceptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following this thread--
In this case, the service invocation was due to a missing 4.5 assembly, specifically system.net.http.  I changed the catch block to include the inner messaging--writing the message to an error table.